# Completing the square to lead to the circle identity

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, geometry, trigonometry

I simplified an identity to get $r=\cos \theta$. I then multiplied both sides by $r$ to get: $r^2=r \cos \theta$. Since $r^2=x^2+y^2, r\cosθ=x^2+y^2$. That is as far as I can get. How would I complete the square to yield $(x−h)^2+(y−k)^2=r^2$ (the equation for a circle?)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$r\cosθ=x$

$x^2-x+y^2=0$

$(x-\dfrac{1}{2})^2+y^2=\dfrac{1}{4}$